# Signs of a bad transmission?

Tags: automatic-transmission, subaru, shifting

I have a 2004 Subaru Legacy L Sedan Automatic. I've been starting to notice in the past few months that the transmission is shifting strange, typically either when the car first starts up, or has been constantly driving for a long time.
For example, when cruising at a low-speed in 2nd gear, when you feel the transmission downshift into 1st it shifts slightly rough, causing the car to bob slightly, and then you can hear/feel a low rumble in the accelerator peddle. I only ever feel it in the lowest gear as I'm driving slowly. It shifts fine from 1st to 2nd and so forth, but from 2nd to 1st has gotten rough. It does not do this in any other gears.
On a sidenote, when it is very cold outside (as it has been lately) right when you start the car the engine is ticking. The ticking subsides when the engine is fully warmed, but I've noticed lately has gotten louder (possibly just in my mind but still cause for concern).
The car just recently broke 130,000 miles so I really hope it's not about to take an expensive repair.
Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level?  Have you had it changed on schedule?

Comment: Fluid level is at the normal level and never changes. I haven't changed the fluid in awhile but it has been changed previously. I'm going to change it again and see if it helps.

Comment: I had a friend check out the engine tick with me, and we both agree that it sounds normal for a Subaru engine.

Comment: Further research has led me to three possible answers: torque bind, bad propeller shaft U-joint or center carrier bearing retainer. Could anyone provide me with some information of how to check the conditions of these?

Comment: To further clarify, this "rumble" typically only happens at around 1200RPM - no sound below or above that. The engine almost sounds as though it is bogged down, or like if you let the RPM dip to low in a high gear on a manual transmission car.